# How can I convert a string to an int?

Tags: java, android

There probably is a really simple answer to this. My goal is to divide the the inputed information x and y and put that into z.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public int x = Integer.parseInt("");
public int y = Integer.parseInt("");
public int z = (y/x);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Button
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    //EditText
    EditText nop = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText cob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    x = Integer.parseInt(nop);
    y = Integer.parseInt(cob);


    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText(z);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Did you type your title in Google ?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? You already seem to be doing this for x and y. The only problem I can imagine is that you specify z only when declaring the member, and you do change the values of x and y, but never update z.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ he actually can convert it look at the conversions of x and y, but he didn't ask the question properly.

Comment: I am not sure where you spent those two hours. Five minutes of reading the javadoc for Integer and its methods ... might have been a better investment. And a side note: most likely, your current problem is the fact that your code throws an exception; coming from : `public int x = Integer.parseInt("");`... as parsing an int from an empty string simply doesn't work.

Comment: x = Integer.parseInt(nop); here you directly trying to parse EditText object use
x = Integer.parseInt(nop.getText().toString());

Comment: @Jagermeister it says "parseInt (java.lang.string) in integer cannot be applied to android.widget.edittext".

Comment: @user5242437 exactly and hence you need to get the data from it using `getText()`

Comment: @user5242437 please read the answers, you have te correct one just there

Comment: @UmaKanth im not sure i understand what youre saying. Could you show it in an answer?

Comment: you allready have @Uma answer.... 10 mintues ago.... **PLEASE READ** you post a question to receive answers, not to keep your mind fighting in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `z` inside your `onclick` function. Or assign it a value inside your function.

Also `nop` and `cob` are editText's get the data in it, use `getText()`.

Because `Integer.parseInt()` accepts only a `String` but not an `editText`, so you must use `getText()` to get the String value in it.

```
x = Integer.parseInt(nop.getText().toString());
y = Integer.parseInt(cob.getText().toString());
 final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          int z = x / y;
          tv.setText(z);
        }
    });
```

Also `z` is declared globally and assigned nothing. But it needs to be assigned a value when ever you click the button, so that your editText changes every time you click the button.

Comment: I was posting almost same answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, the mistake is the same so we might get the same answer :)

Comment: a bit explanation about scope of `z` and when to divide will be nice too ;), OP seems to be a bit confusing declaring `z=x/y` as attribute

Comment: Thank you guys for your help

Comment: Did you understand why I did it that way? Or else you need some more clarity about something?

Answer (score 0):

Convert first as a string from Edittext then make it as Integer.

```
String Val1 = nop.getText().toString();
String Val2 =cob.getText().toString();
x = Integer.parseInt(val1);
y = Integer.parseInt(val2);
```